# Magento super attribute configuration

Tags: magento, configuration, attributes, super

I have a store, with the Mico AVP price variation extension installed.
This allows you to determine a price based on selected attribute data, and apply discounts.

This is based upon basic public signs. Health and safety, general notices etc etc.
As part of a config product process...a product has 2 custom options. Height and width. I have an observer which adds these to a product when new, or updated...if they are not present.

I have a third option called material. I have created three simple products...onr for each material. These are assigned to a 'sign' product. 
In the super attribute configuration part...i add set prices, which are used to help calculate the final price of the product.

At the moment...i would need to add this info, for each configurable sign i create. And i wanted to automate this. I thought, that if i add the prices to the actual SIMPLE PRODUCTS (eg, the material products i created), that it would use this info. But it doesnt. I HAVE to set the 'super attribute configuration' prices.

I am trying to understand this area more, given it doesnt work as expected. Why do i have to set a 's-a-c' price...why wont it use the set product price instead, if no s-a-c price set?

Hope this makes sense. Heres a screenshot. I want to change the product price (currently seen as 0.02)..and use these rather then the decimal 'prices' you see. Then i would only have to update the 'material' products when a price changes for a paticular material.

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I see that Magento itself says "The price of the associated products is not used for calculation." in configurable products.

Check out http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/additional-configurable-product-settings
especially the last line which I just quoted above.

Hope this helps.